# How to move title of UITabBarItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Can somebody tell me please how can I move title of UITabBarItem for example 2px to top?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Solution:

```
UITabBarItem *item = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]; 
item.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -5.0);
```

Comment: Surprisingly in swift: `item.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -5.0))` (only setter function available in XCode 6.1)

Comment: In Swift2/Xcode7 the setter function is gone and you can use the normal property for setting the value. `item.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal:0,vertical:1000)`

Answer (score 15):

> Update for Swift 3

Put this code inside `UITabBarController`:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -5)
```

Credit goes to [Tim Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618268/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-text-position-in-uitabbar-or-uitabbaritem)

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4
Like me, if you are creating tab bar controller inside some other controller just after adding all controller you can loop through the tab bar items and change title and positioning and font

```
for (index,tabBarItem) in tabBarController.tabBar.items!.enumerated() {
        tabBarItem.image = nil //if you only want title and no Image
        tabBarItem.title = titleArray[index] //setting your title based on some array
        let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)] // changeing font and height of the text
        tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
        tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -10.0) // updating the title positon 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabbarItem.titlePositionAdjustment` to adjust.

In case you want to do much more with that then access tabbaritem subview and find label on `tabbar.subviews`. For example

```
 int i = 0;
for (NSObject *view in self.tabBar.subviews)
{
    MTLog(@"%@", view);
    if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(subviews)])
    {
        for (NSObject *childView in ((UIView *)view).subviews)
        {
            if ([childView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
            {
                if (i > (titlesArray.count - 1))
                    break;
                UILabel *label = (UILabel *)childView;
                NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:titlesArray[i] attributes:@{
                                                                                                                                            NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:9]
                                                                                                                                            }];

                NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
                [style setMinimumLineHeight:26];
                [style setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

                [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                                         value:style
                                         range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
                label.attributedText = attributedString;
                i++;
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't... you might be able to hack your way around it but that wouldn't be easy and could break your app on future iOS updates.

Best bet would be to create your own UITabBar system... heres a good guide you could take a look at..

http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/

Comment: I found this solution:
UITabBarItem *item = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
item.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -5.0);

Comment: Ahh.. sorry, last time I looked for this feature it wasn't there... reading the class reference for it now its only available for iOS5 + so you may want to check if the function is available before calling it if your app is designed to work with pre-iOS 5... you can do this like so... `if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitlePositionAdjustment:)]) { item.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -5.0); }`