# Is there a way to change the text position in UITabBar or UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

[image]

This is a custom tab bar I intended to put up on the screen. However,  my partner want the text to be slightly up. How can I do so?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Why don't you just have an empty title property for your view controller and add the title to your custom images for the tab?

**UPDATE:** For the sake of completeness of answer; from comments and [ios tabbar put text in the middle when no image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586411/ios-tabbar-put-text-in-the-middle-when-no-image)

`[tab.tabBarItem setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -10)]`

Comment: Good enough. I found a better way:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586411/ios-tabbar-put-text-in-the-middle-when-no-image

Comment: ended up selecting your answers because it's more comprehensive :)

Comment: Why (0, -10) ? I don't understand... Can you explain me?

Comment: @LKM 0 means no horizontal offset, -10 moves the text up.

Comment: You also can do it in storyboard.

Answer (score 46):

You probably want to apply this offset globally, so I'd suggest

Obj-C

```
[UITabBarItem appearance].titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, -4);
```

Swift:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4)
```

Comment: correction for Swift: `UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -4)`

Comment: If you just want to adjust the vertical position (in swift) you might also use this `UITabBarItem.appearance().titlePositionAdjustment.vertical = -4`

Answer (score 11):

Here's the same trick with Interface builder:

[image]

Comment: Nice one! Also introduces the user defined runtime attributes section, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can do it directly from Interface Builder (Custom Offset in Title Position), like this:
[image: link]

Comment: Just tried it and it works, however, when you go into landscape mode, your text will not be centered to your image anymore (because in landscape mode image and label are positioned horizontaly, not vertically)

Answer (score 7):

For iOS 13 and later:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
           appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -10)
           appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -10) 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer here: [ios tabbar put text in the middle when no image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586411/ios-tabbar-put-text-in-the-middle-when-no-image) will try this one and see how it goes :)

Update: It works. Only 1 line of code.